# Issue with faces after merged loops and move operation

Tags: modeling, vertices, faces

I forgot to turn off auto merge and therefore few edges of the two loops (transparent faces on the screenshot) merged into one. I dissolved the loop and added a new one. The grid was restored. But after i initiate move operation the faces are still not moving properly. Tried deleting vertices, edges, faces, still not working. Tried merging vertices by distance. Not a flip normals issue. What can i possibly do to fix it? [image]

Comment: Fixed by deleting transparent faces and extruding them one by one from the faces which are going by the selected loop. Extruding from the top (opposite of the selected loop) would give me same issue.

Comment: Hello and congrats on solving it :). Please post your comment as an answer. Then you can accept it (after 2 days) so others can find it more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by deleting transparent faces and extruding them one by one from the faces which are going by the selected loop.